# Conversion and reactor time

Tags: kinetics

Lets say it takes my batch reactor 3 hours for 35% conversion.

If I wanted to find how long it would take for 15% then,

35-15 = 20,

then 3 hours/0.20 = 0.15 hours for 15% conversion.

I am not too sure if this is correct. Some guidance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I am very curious how did you come to "then 3 hours/0.20 = 0.15 hours for 15% conversion."

Comment: For one, in chemical engineering, to describe the duration about how long a volume element remains in a reactor (e.g., batch reactor, continous flow reactor) is the _residence time_ (e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residence_time).  For two, knowing the conversion after a (mean / average) residence time is only one part of the equation; depending on the rate order, rates _may_ depend on the time of reaction, too.  Have a look at the rate laws (including their integrated form); zero, first; second, fractional order.

Answer (score 2):

The result very depends on the reaction stoichiometry, kinetic order and the ratio of reagents, as  "cheaper" reagents are often in excess.

Let suppose the conversion equation is $\ce{A + B -> C}$ and the reaction kinetics is of the second order.

Then 
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}[C]}{\mathrm{d}t}=k \cdot \ce{[A][B]}$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}[A]}{\mathrm{d}t}=-k \cdot \ce{[A][B]}$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}[B]}{\mathrm{d}t}=-k \cdot \ce{[A][B]}$$

If the stoichiometric ration is managed, then  \ce{[A] = [B]}

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}[C]}{\mathrm{d}t}=k \cdot \ce{[A]}^2$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}[A]}{\mathrm{d}t}=-k \cdot \ce{[A]}^2$$

If we integrate the function over the time:
$$\int_{a_0}^{a}{\frac {\mathrm{d}[A]}{ -k \cdot \ce{[A]}^2 }}=\int_0^{T}{  \mathrm{d}t}$$
$$\frac {1}{k} \cdot [\frac 1A - \frac 1{a_0}]=T$$
$$\frac 1A =kT +  \frac 1{a_0}$$
$$A =\frac 1{kT +  \frac 1{a_0}}$$